# why do i get a 404 when i import in js

Tags: javascript

im new to javascript and im trying to make a simple web app, when making the login page i wanted to make the script that is directly running in the browser call another script to do the back end

now i got frustrated and deleted the code but here is a simple example of how it works...

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Login into to your account!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="login">
    <label>Username:</label>

    <input type="text" id="userNameF">
    <br>

    
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password"id="passwordF">
        <br>


    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Login">

        <h1 id="warning">H</h1>
            </div>
    

    <div id="page">

        <h1 id="balance"></h1>


            <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Amount">
            <input type="text" id="receptor" placeholder="Receptor">
            <input type="button" value="Send" id="sendBtn">
            <h1 id="warning2">H</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="./dist/login.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

login.js

```
import { yes } from "./ye";
```

ye.js

```
export function d(yes){
    console.log(yes)
}
```

i was expecting no error and proceeding with the code normally,

what i got was

GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/ye net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It's trying to load `/dist/ye`, yet your file is named `ye.js`. Unless you have some build process or transpiling/active server that's serving the JS you have to fix this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, when you're bringing in files in a modular way, like using `import`, you should include the file extension. So, instead of just saying `ye`, you should say `ye.js`. This helps JavaScript know exactly what file you're referring to. If you leave out the extension, JavaScript might get confused and not find the file you want to import, hence its attempt to import `/ye` instead of `/ye.js`

(Also, if `ye.js` is exporting `d`, and you are importing `{ yes }`, the code will not execute successfully. Instead, you should `export default d`, and `import yes` (apposed to `import { yes }`))